# "Post" and "GET" requests from PhoneGap on iOS to PHP on server not working

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, post, cordova

From a PhoneGap app on iOS I am trying to do a jQuery Post call to a PHP file that can be found on a server.
This is the command:

```
$.post({url:'http://example.com/uploadtest/addContent.php', data: JSONstring, success:contentSent});
```

On the server I'm logging any occasion when `addContent.php` is called. Unfortunately, it never is. Neither is the `contentSent()` method:

```
function contentSent(data, textStatus)
{
    console.log("Did it get into the callback? Status:" + textStatus);
    var response = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log("Response: " + data);
}
```

My problem is that I get absolutely no feedback, no error message, nothing. It's just as if that line of code wouldn't be there. 
Does someone know what the problems is, or at least how I may get some kind of status message / error code?

**Update 1:** *"GET" shows the same behavior.*

**Update 2:** *The syntax I'm using in the upper example is faulty, but this (AFAIK correct) syntax doesn't work either: `$.get('http://example.com/uploadtest/getTest.php', JSONstring, successFunction);`*

**Update 3:** *The problem does not seem to be device-related, it shows the same behavior from the emulator.*

Comment: Have you tried from a non-phoneGap app ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know Objective-C so couldn't easily write a test-app for that.

Comment: Have you tried calling it in google chrome?  Using developper tools when can help you see http connection status.

Comment: I now have tried creating a POST using Google Chrome with the plugin "Postman" (quite nice). It works. `$jsonvalue = $_POST['JSONstring'];` gets the correct string. But from the PhoneGap app it still doesn't.

Comment: Another update: GET doesn't work either, but the general connectivity seems to work: `$.get({url:'http://example.com/uploadtest/getTest.php', data: JSONstring, success:successFunction});` shows the same behavior: No output, and it never reaches the server. But looking at ` var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;` shows me the network connectivity is fine.

Comment: I used the wrong syntax (the curly braces seem to be only for $.ajax), but with the correct one it still doesn't work:   `$.get('http://example.com/uploadtest/getTest.php', JSONstring, successFunction);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, and it was way to simple. 
In the whitelist (Supporting Files/PhoneGap.plist) I had put my domain ("http://example.com") but that wasn't enough.

Putting an asterisk (*) there was the solution...